# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable, for comparing two lines

Tags: python, numpy, similarity

> I tried to compare two plotted lines. I first load two data files and assign the x and y, and then tried to even the points on the x axes. However, an error popped out:
>
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "/Users/renzha/Documents/compare two lines.py", line 33, in 
> > `xnew = data1[:,0] ( min(x), max(x), num = points)`
> > TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

> Original code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd 
import scipy.stats as ss
data1 = np.loadtxt(filedialog.askopenfilename(), delimiter='\t')
data2 = np.loadtxt(filedialog.askopenfilename(), delimiter='\t')
x = data1[:,0]
y = data1[:,1]
x2 = data2[:,0]
y2 = data2[:,1]
f = interp1d(x, y)
f2 = interp1d(x2,y2)
points = 150
xnew = data1[:,0] ( min(x), max(x), num = points) 
xnew2 = data2[:,0] ( min(x2), max(x2), num = points) 
ynew = f(xnew) 
ynew2 = f2(xnew2) 
plt.plot(x,y, 'r', x2, y2, 'g', xnew, ynew, 'r--', xnew2, ynew2, 'g--')
plt.show()
print (ssd.correlation(ynew, ynew2))
print (np.correlate(ynew, ynew2, mode='valid'))
print (np.corrcoef(ynew, ynew2)) 
print (ss.spearmanr(ynew, ynew2))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the errors said, your data`data1[:,0]` and `data2[:,0]` are numpy arrays. I guess you are trying to apply a function with parameters `( min(x), max(x), num = points)`, check again the code to see which function should be used there. Looking at the name of the parameters, maybe `numpy.linspace(start, stop, num= ...)` could help.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace